# Saving to SharedPreferences from custom DialogPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I've currently got a preferences screen, and I've created a custom class that extends `DialogPreference` and is called from within my Preferences. My preferences data seems store/retrieve from `SharedPreferences` without an issue, but I'm trying to add 2 more sets of settings from the `DialogPreference`.

Basically I have two issues that I have not been able to find. Every site I've seen gives me the same standard info to save/restore data and I'm still having problems. Firstly I'm trying to save a username and password to my `SharedPreferences` (visible in the last block of code) and if possibly I'd like to be able to do it in the`onClick()`.

My preferences XML that calls my `DialogPreference`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <PreferenceCategory>   
 <com.rone.optusmon.AccDialog
  android:key="AccSettings"
  android:title="Account Settings"
  android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
  android:positiveButtonText="Save" />   

 </PreferenceCategory> 
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My Custom DialogPreference Class file:

```java
package com.rone.optusmon;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AccDialog extends DialogPreference implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {


 private TextView mUsername, mPassword;
 private EditText mUserbox, mPassbox;
 CharSequence mPassboxdata, mUserboxdata;
 private CheckBox mShowchar;
 private Context mContext;

 private int mWhichButtonClicked;


 public AccDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  mContext = context;

 }

 @Override
 protected View onCreateDialogView() {

// Access default SharedPreferences
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);


  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
   layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
   layout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
   layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);

   mUsername = new TextView(mContext);
    mUsername.setText("Username:");
    mUsername.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mUsername.setPadding(0, 8, 0, 3);

   mUserbox = new EditText(mContext);
    mUserbox.setSingleLine(true); 
    mUserbox.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

   mPassword = new TextView(mContext);
    mPassword.setText("Password:");
    mPassword.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

   mPassbox = new EditText(mContext);
    mPassbox.setSingleLine(true);
    mPassbox.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

   mShowchar = new CheckBox(mContext);
    mShowchar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mShowchar_listener);
    mShowchar.setText("Show Characters");
    mShowchar.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mShowchar.setChecked(false);
    if(!mShowchar.isChecked()) {
     mPassbox.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
    }


   layout.addView(mUsername);
   layout.addView(mUserbox);
   layout.addView(mPassword);
   layout.addView(mPassbox);
   layout.addView(mShowchar);

  return layout; 
 } 


 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  mWhichButtonClicked = which;
  // if statement to set save/cancel button roles
  if (mWhichButtonClicked == -1) {
   Toast.makeText(mContext, "Save was clicked\nUsername: " + mUserbox.getText().toString() +"\nPassword is: " + mPassbox.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
   // Save user preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putString("usernamekey", mUserbox.getText().toString());
   editor.putString("passwordkey", mPassbox.getText().toString());
   editor.commit();

  }
  else {
   Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cancel was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 } 
}
```

My main activity test code:

```java
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();   

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append("\nThe monitor will refresh every "+ pref.getString("refreshfreq", "30 minutes"));
    builder.append("\nThe skin chosen is "+ pref.getString("skinkey", "null"));
    builder.append("\nThe style chosen is "+ pref.getString("stylekey", "% used"));
    builder.append("\nThe font chosen is "+ pref.getString("fontkey", "Calibri"));
    builder.append("\nThe font color is "+ pref.getString("fontcolkey", "White"));
    builder.append("\nYour username is "+ pref.getString("usernamekey", "not set yet"));
    builder.append("\nYour password is "+ pref.getString("passwordkey", "not set yet"));

    Toast.makeText(Optusmon.this, builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

In my `SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` line, Eclipse says "The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(AccDialog) is undefined for the type AccDialog". I've attempted to change the context to my preferences class, use a blank context and I've also tried naming my SharedPrefs and using `getSharedPreferences()` as well. I'm just not sure exactly what I'm doing here.

As I'm quite new to Java/Android/coding in general, could you please be as detailed as possible with any help, eg. which of my files I need to write the code in and whereabouts in that file should I write it (i.e. `onCreate()`, `onClick()`, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `onCreate()` you returned before execute this line, so Eclipse says it's unreachable.
In your `onClick()` try:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```

should be OK

Comment: I didn't think it would make a difference being after the 'return layout' as it was outside of the layout regardless, but I moved it to the line after "protected View onCreateDialogView() {" and the issue disappeared. It also resolved my issue in the onClick() block.

Thank You

Comment: Ah ok. I've come across another issue after implementing this fix and I've edited the above code and added a paragraph at the bottom to explain it. It still doesn't seem to be saving as intended, or else it is but I'm not reading it correctly.

Comment: I feel absolutely stupid for taking a whole day to figure this out, but I left my editor.commit() out, which is why the preferences weren't saving. You can look over it 300 times and still miss the simplest errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. In the onCreate() code, Eclipse says it's "unreachable code" and recommends I delete the entire line. In my onClick() code, the same error as before remains.